# Computing the dimension of $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(D))$, where $D \subset X$ is a divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$. Let $X/k$ be a smooth, projective, connected variety over $k$ of dimension $d$. Let $i: D \subset X$ be an effective divisor isomorphic over $k$ to $\mathbb{P}^{d-1}$. I'm trying to compute the dimension of $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(D))$. Here is what I've tried so far: by Serre Duality, 
$$H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(D)) = H^d(X, \mathcal{O}_X(-D) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \omega_X)^{\ast}.$$
There is a short exact sequence of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules given by
$$ 0 \to  \mathcal{O}_X(-D) \otimes \omega_X \to \omega_X \to  i_\ast( \mathcal{O}_D)  \otimes \omega_X \to 0.$$
Passing to cohomology, there is an exact sequence
$$ H^{d-1}(X, i_\ast( \mathcal{O}_D)  \otimes \omega_X) \to  H^d(X, \mathcal{O}_X(-D) \otimes \omega_X) \to  H^d(X,\omega_X) \to H^d(X, i_\ast( \mathcal{O}_D)  \otimes \omega_X).$$

The idea is to use the above exact sequence to compute $h^d(X, \mathcal{O}_X(-D) \otimes \omega_X)$ and the we are done by Serre Duality. We know that $h^d(X, \omega_X) = 1$, which is an encouraging start.

What would be useful now is some isomorphism of the form
$$H^r(X, i_\ast( \mathcal{O}_D) \otimes \omega_X) \cong  H^r(D,???)$$
as this would  give, for example, that $H^d(X, i_\ast( \mathcal{O}_D)\otimes \omega_X) = 0$ (by dimension considerations) and it would probably make things easier as $D \cong \mathbb{P}^{d-1}$. Ideally, $H^{d-1}(X, i_\ast( \mathcal{O}_D)\otimes \omega_X) = 0$ and $H^d(X, i_\ast( \mathcal{O}_D)\otimes \omega_X) = 0$, making the computations super easy (but I'm not sure these both vanish).

However, I'm stuck and I'm not sure that the above strategy is a good one. Help please!

Comment: With no other information, how do you compute it? It can be different for different situations.

Comment: @Mohan What other information would be useful to compute it? I can put other geometric conditions on $X$ if necessary, apart from conditions on the dimension (I want it to be arbitrary, even if I know that for $d=1,2$ I can use Riemann-Roch to compute stuff) and on $\omega_X$ (if it is trivial, for example, then I know how to compute things).

Comment: You can use the projection formula: $i_*(\mathcal{O}_D)\otimes \omega_X\cong i_*(\mathcal{O}_D\otimes i^*(\omega_X))$. Then use that $H^n(X,i_*\mathcal F)\cong H^n(Y,\mathcal F)$, where $i:Y\to X$ is a closed embedding.

Comment: As danneks said, you can use the projection formula, you can also use the adjunction formula :
$$H^r(X,i_*(\mathcal{O}_D\otimes\omega_X))=H^r(X,i_*i^*\omega_X)=H^r(D,\omega_D\otimes \mathcal{O}_D(-D))$$
Since you know that $D\simeq\mathbb{P}^{d-1}$, you have $\omega_D\simeq \mathcal{O}_D(-d)$. You now need to compute $\mathcal{O}_D(-D)$, but without further hypothesis, I don't think you can say more.

Comment: @Roland and danneks: thanks!